# How to convert String to File in Java and vice versa?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

**Converting String to File**: I am passing a file to an action in controller

```
redirect(action:"downloadFile", params:[file:temp_file])
```

But when I do

```
def file = params.file
file.getName();
```

It give me error `cannot cast object 'java.lang.String' to 'java.io.File'`

How to convert `String` to `File`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `params.file` is a file that user're uploading, you have to use following:

```
def file = request.getFile('file')
//where 'file' is a name of parameter, from <input type='file'/>
```

please read more about [file upload in Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.9%20Uploading%20Files)

If you're trying to send this file to user's browser then:

```
String filename = '/reports/pdfreport9090.pdf'
response.contentType = "application/pdf"
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=$filename") 
File f = new File(filename)
response.outputStream << f.newInputStream()
response.outputStream.flush()
```

Comment: Actually i have another question , i am returning a string file(/reports/pdfreport9090.pdf) from the method .i need to download this file in the controller action .so how to get the file

Comment: what you mean 'download file in controller action'??? Are you trying to send this file to browser?

Comment: Yes, sending the file to browser ,this action is done in the controller method

Comment: the file is getting stored on  server, but it is not asking to download on the client side (browser) i have kept files in web-app directory on my server(local machine).what is the problem?

Comment: i can't understand your problem :(

Comment: @splix let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1729/discussion-between-vinay-and-splix)